# How can I reinstall "Installer.app"?

Tags: macos, install

When I double-click "Installer.app" in Macintosh HD ▸ System ▸ Library ▸ CoreServices, a dialog pops up that says "You can’t open the application “Installer.app” because it may be damaged or incomplete."

Also, the icon for "Installer.app" has a white circle over it.

I have no idea how this happened.

OS X Yosemite version 10.10.2

Comment: You could move it from another mac running the same OS. The only "official" way is to reinstall Yosemite

Comment: That is likely, there is an off chance that just running the latest point upgrade to Yosemite will work, unless it, too, uses the installer.app to do its magic. But just running the Yosemite installer *should* be completely safe as only o/s level files are being replaced.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me, too. I do not know the reason exactly, but I think it has something to do with the upgrade to the 10.10.3 beta.

My Installer.app (located in: `/System/Library/CoreServices/` file had a circle on it at the file size was just 52 KB.

Luckily I had another Mac (running plain 10.10.2) around and could just copy the file over with a USB stick.